# how to add a function if the payment with Stripe is true

Tags: function, flutter, stripe-payments

I made a payment with Stripe and I would like to execute a function if the payment is validated attached my code

```
    if (response.status == 'succeeded') {
    return new StripeTransactionResponse(
        message: 'Payement Accepté',
        success: true
        mail() //is my function 
    );


  } else {
    return new StripeTransactionResponse(
        message: 'Echec du payement',
        success: false
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is the function failing? You may have to add the ; to the end of the function mail();

Comment: unfortunately it's the same